# Scroll relative to current position Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to scroll a div relative to its current position when clicking on an element using jquery. But it has to scroll after 3000 miliseconds, so tried to delay it. Now it scroll 300 px relative to the top immidiatly after clicking. if i click again nothing happends.

this is the code so far:

```
$('#scroll').click(function(){              
            $('.vluchtelinginfo').delay(3000).scrollTop(+300);
        });
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: this is a misnomer - the actual question is about timing, not about scrolling or positioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how `delay()` works.

In your case, use

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.vluchtelinginfo').scrollTop(+300);
});
```

Per the documentation for `delay()`

> Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will
>   not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not
>   use the effects queue.

Comment: Thanks, this helpt me out. Do you also have an idea for the scroll thing?

Comment: my code now is: $('#scroll').click(function(){ 
  var delay = 3000;   
    setTimeout(function() {
     $('.vluchtelinginfo').scrollTop(300);
    }, delay);
   });

Answer (score 4):

Brad M's recommendation about using `setTimeout` is one way to get what you want. `scrollTop()` is not listed among the "effect" provided by jQuery and thus won't be affected by `delay()` because `delay()` only affects effects.

However, it is possible to use `animate()` to make an effect out of scrolling, for instance the following should animate the scrolling:

```
$scrollable.animate({scrollTop: x});
```

Since `animate()` is an "effect", it should be affected by `delay()`. So you could do:

```
$scrollable.delay(3000).animate({scrollTop: x});
```

However, there is another problem you ran into: when `scrollTop(x)` is called `x` is an *absolute value*, not a *relative one*. Calling `scrollTop(+300)` is exactly the same as calling `scrollTop(300)`. The `+` symbol has no special meaning in that context. If you want your scrolling to be relative, then you need to first get the previous scrollTop value and add to it the relative distance you want to scroll. For instance,

```
$scrollable.delay(3000).animate({scrollTop: $scrollable.scrollTop() + 300});
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lddubeau/945JJ/) puts the above principles to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this...

```
$("#scroll").click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".vluchtelinginfo").css("top", $(".vluchtelinginfo").offset().top + 300);
    }, 3000);
});
```